# Use Windows Login Credential to login in an application

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, authentication

We have a VB.Net based application having its own login mechanism. We have a login form to enter credential and we check this credential against pre-stored entires in database that are entered during user registration.

We wish to scrap the above mechanism and use Windows Login Credential in order to login. System automatically detects login name and display it in read-only label. User enters his/her password, the system will check against the password that will be stored by windows and on success we will allow the user to proceed further.

Summary : Access (Read-Only) Login Credential (User Name and Password) of Windows Login from out VB.Net Based application for user-verifcation.

Comment: Accesing the user name is easy, you have it in [`Environment.UserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you need to access active directory to process the login check. You have sample code [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Add-Window-Authentication-833ba913) (it's C#, but it's just the same in vb.net)

Comment: What if user changes their username to their account, how do you handle that? If thats the case they wouldnt be in the system as this new user would they?...

Comment: You might want to consider that given they have already logged into Windows and been authenticated, they have already proved they are who they say they are, and little extra is achieved by doing that again. So you might have to fall back on a list of users in your db after all, but use the retrieved username as @Pikoh says.

Comment: @Codexer, This is a highly specialized application designed for a particular industry and as per standard norms you are not allowed to modify or delete user information (except for password). IT department of the company (user) disables the ability to change user name, hence this condition should not occur.

Comment: @peterG, Before printing reports or performing any privileged operation explicit user authentication is must. I am also required to verify password. Our system consist of both desktop application and OEM hardware. It is an multi-user, embedded, autonomous and parallel system. Once the software is started it is left unattended. e.g. : User A (in-charge) might start desktop application and leave it running. User B might use our Embedded Hardware 1, User C might use our Hardware 2 and so on. In this case authentication of User A is must on desktop software while verifying and signing reports.

Comment: @Pikoh, Thanks for solution regarding user name.